# daylight saving time for display-time-world

Tags: emacs

I'm in a time zone without daylight saving time. so that

```
(calendar-dst-starts 2012)
nil
```

the value of calendar-daylight-savings-starts-time is 0.

I'm using windows xp and emacs 24. How could I get the display-time-world show time with daylight saving time, for example, New York EST5EDT? Default the daylight saving time will not be adjusted to the displayed time.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused - what is meant by `EST5EDT`

Comment: @Adel, that means the standard time zone is Eastern Standard Time, it's 5 hours behind UTC, and during [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) it's Eastern Daylight Time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about this, but if I configure Emacs so that `(calendar-dst-starts 2012)` returns `nil` and `calendar-daylight-savings-starts-time` is `0` (neither being default values for me), I get the same results from `display-time-world` as I do otherwise.

If I look at the variable `display-time-world-list` it says

```
Its value is (("PST8PDT" "Seattle")
 ("EST5EDT" "New York")
 ("GMT0BST" "London")
 ("CET-1CDT" "Paris")
 ("IST-5:30" "Bangalore")
 ("JST-9" "Tokyo"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve ever dealt with time in PHP you’ve probably been burnt by daylight savings time before.

PHP does provide a way to check if a time is in daylight savings time or not, it’s as simple as using a capital i as the format:

```
if (date('I', time()))
{
    echo 'We’re in DST!';
}
else
{
    echo 'We’re not in DST!';
}
```

compare daylight saving time

https://www.timehubzone.com/worldclock/extends